# Uncaught TypeError in Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I'm developing a single page application in Angular 8.3, and it gives me errors like

> Uncaught TypeError: _jp.a1z2yq3 is not a function
>       at jsonp?c=_jp.a1z2yq3:1 (anonymous) @ jsonp?c=_jp.a1z2yq3:1

or

> Uncaught TypeError: _jp.apxn3ot is not a function
>       at jsonp?c=_jp.apxn3ot:1 (anonymous) @ jsonp?c=_jp.apxn3ot:1

As far as I can tell by following the trace, these are in generated code and lead nowhere:

`/**/_jp.apxn3ot("o");`

I'm using Chrome for testing, the error is there in the new version of Edge and Firefox too.

I've tried searching for the error, but given the generated nature of it, I've had no success in doing so.

Is this an error in Angular or my application? It seems to work fine otherwise, but I want to get rid of these errors. I migrated from 8.1 recently and don't remember seeing these before (not a 100% sure). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your full stack trace? Generated functions are a product of compiler and builder, so the actual error must happen on a higher level.

Comment: This is the whole stack trace I can see in my dev tools, it doesn't go deeper.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, from this stack trace we can know that this generated function refers to an anonymous function, i.e. without a name or identifier. In your code, you need to find this function in your code. This will at least narrow down your search. If you are not as familiar with the concept, here is a quick refresher: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions Take a look at some provided examples and find out if you have those in your code. One of those will be your buggy typeerror